# Increasing the speed of prepending and appending a million calculations

Tags: java

this code is being used to go through a million calculations and I'm not quite following what needs to be done in order to increase the speed. I was given the tip of including a new array (tempIndex, which is currently unused) but did not know how to utilize it nor what needed to be changed within the get() and set() methods.

```
public class IAList {
    private int[] a;
    private int length;
    private int[] tempIndex;
    public IAList() {
        length = 0;
        a = new int[4];
        tempIndex = new int[4];
    }

    public int get(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(i+"");
        }
        return a[i];
    }

    public int size() {
        return length;
    }

    public void set(int i, int x) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(i+"");
        }
        a[i] = x;
    }

    public void add(int x) {
        if (length >= a.length) {
            int[] b = new int[a.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                b[i] = a[i];
            }
            a = b;
        }
        a[length] = x;
        length = length + 1;
    }

    public void addBefore(int x) {
        if (length >= a.length) {
            int[] b = new int [a.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                b[i] = a[i];
            }
            a = b;
        }
        int i;
        for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
        }
        a[0] = x;
        length++;
        }
    }
```

As seen here, the calculations complete but take several minutes. What should I do?

````
Now starting tests. You'll see an 'Everything looks OK!' message if everything is ok!
Creating two IALists, a and b.
Adding the numbers 1 through 10 to a by calling a.add(1); a.add(2); etc.
Initial functionality looks OK. Now testing addBefore with a single value.
OK. Now addBefore-ing 90 more values.
OK. Now adding 200 values.
OK. Now alternating addBefore and append with a bunch of values.
OK. Now running a speed test addBefore-ing and adding a million values.
OK. Now running a speed test alternating addBefore and append with 100,000 zeros.
OK, but you took 192675 milliseconds, which seems too long (I'm expecting 1000 or less)```
````

Comment: System.arraycopy is faster than copying „manually“ (when your backing array grows ). Also, for, if that is allowed by your lecturer, adding a constructor parameter with a initial size for the backing array can help

Comment: @Felix this is not true once JIT kicks in.

Comment: You could start by getting rid of all the tests that lead to `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Java will do those tests and that throw anyway. You are just duplicating work.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an append method?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have written a list-like datatype which supports adding adding 'at the back' or adding 'at the front'.

The code that adds 'at the back' isn't really the problem. It just sets a single array index, unless the backing array is 'filled to capacity', in which case it makes an array copy. Yes, `System.arraycopy` is in theory faster, but in practice it usually won't be a particularly noticable difference. Feel free to read up an `System.arraycopy` and use that instead, but it won't provide a significant speed boost.

The code that adds 'at the front', on the other hand, oh boy. That will run a complete loop throughout the entire array **every time** you invoke it, in order to shift all elements up one slot to make room.

Therein lies the problem. That will take longer and longer as the list grows larger and larger. `System.arraycopy` will not fix that issue.

There is a solution, though: **RINGS**.

Instead of envisioning your `int[]` as a thing with a start and an end, as if it is a line, take that line and bend it so that the ends touch. It's a ring. Consider a `new int[100]`. Imagine we state that there is neither a start nor an end to this, like a ring. It is not infinite size (it is '100 large'), but, after element 56, there is element 57. After element 99, there is element 0. For this to work, imagine that there is nothing special about 0 or 99. It's just another index, and *ALL* indexes have a next and previous. You'll need to emulate this ring in your code with some very simplistic math (going 'down' from the 0 should start at `length -1`, and going 'up' from the `length -1` slot should go to 0, but that's all you really need).

In your current implementation, you have a backing array of, say, size 150, but your data structure only has length, say, 100. In that case, that array's elements at index 0 through 99 represent the actual elements in the list, and the remaining 50 slots are just there for future use.

In the ring, what happens then is that only an arc of the ring is used. In your current implementation, the 'start' of the subrange across your backing array that contains the real data is fixed at 0, and you track the 'end' of the subrange with the `length` field.

The voodoo magic trick here is that, with a ring, and by 'floating' the start, **you can now quickly grow from both the front AND the back**.

To add elements at the back, add them at the right place and increment the 'end of the sublist' marker. To add elements to the front, add them to the right place and decrement the 'front of the sublist' marker. Keep in mind that it's a ring, so 'add 1 to the end marker' may involve turning `99` into `0` if the current backing array capacity is 100. Similarly, 'decrement start-of-segment by 1 and then write this number into that space' may involve 'decrementing 0', which would then mean the index becomes 99.

You still need to write the code to create a new larger array and copy all elements over if the backing array runs out of capacity.

`get(int idx)` becomes a little more complicated. For example, if your backing array has 150 elements, 'start' is currently at 140, and 'end' is at 88, then `.get(55)` means you need to return `backingArray[45]`. The math is fortunately simple if you know about the modulo operator (`%`). The module operator is like divide, except it returns the remainder and discards the actual result. So, `start + index % backingArray.length` is what you want: `(140 + 45) % 150` is 45, as you'd want.

You'll need to play around with the concept some, and experiment with modulo to write the code in a succint manner.

Keep in mind that the aim is to **NOT** copy the entire array over in either the add-to-the-back *or* add-to-the-front operation unless the backing array's filled up. The ring solution is how you get there.